# Fetch Zendesk Tickets into SQL (JSON Handling)

Tags: c#, json

In the Zendesk Developer Blog i found a helpfull Entry(https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/getting-and-creating-tickets-with-.net).

I used the Code from the Article in an C# ConsoleApp for testing:

```
using System;
using ConsoleApplication1.Properties;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Ticket
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string external_id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string recipient { get; set; }
        public int requester_id { get; set; }
        public int submitter_id { get; set; }
        public int assignee_id { get; set; }
        public int organization_id { get; set; }
        public int group_id { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly string requestUri = "https://xxx.zendesk.com/";
        private static readonly string username = Settings.Default.Username;
        private static readonly string password = Settings.Default.Password;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(requestUri);
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
            var request = new RestRequest("/api/v2/tickets.json", Method.GET);
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            var ticket = JObject.Parse(content);

            foreach (var pair in ticket)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, and i receive the following Data:

```
tickets: [
  {
    "url": "xxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json",
    "id": 1,
    "external_id": null,
    "via": {
      "channel": "sample_ticket",
      "source": {
        "from": {},
        "to": {},
        "rel": null
      }
    },
    "created_at": "2015-10-12T12:08:25Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-12T18:15:13Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "subject": "Beispielticket: erster Blick auf das Ticket",
    "raw_subject": "Beispielticket: erster Blick auf das Ticket",
    "description": "Hallo xxx,\n\nE-Mails, Chats, Voicemails und Tweets werden in Zendesk in Form von Tickets erfasst. Geben Sie oben Ihre Antwort
ein und klicken Sie dann auf "Einreichen", um sie zu senden. Um auszuprobieren, wie eine E-Mail zu einem Ticket wird, senden Sie eine Nachricht an sup
port@xxx.zendesk.com.\n",
    "priority": "normal",
    "status": "open",
    "recipient": null,
    "requester_id": 1371652071,
    "submitter_id": 1371651941,
    "assignee_id": null,
    "organization_id": null,
    "group_id": 24976891,
    "collaborator_ids": [],
    "forum_topic_id": null,
    "problem_id": null,
    "has_incidents": false,
    "due_at": null,
    "tags": [
      "zendesk-beispiel"
    ],
    "custom_fields": [
      {
        "id": 28089621,
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "id": 28087191,
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "id": 28087201,
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "satisfaction_rating": null,
    "sharing_agreement_ids": [],
    "fields": [
      {
        "id": 28089621,
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "id": 28087191,
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "id": 28087201,
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "brand_id": 782281
  },
  {
    "url": "xxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json",
    "id": 2,
    "external_id": null,
    "via": {
      "channel": "web",
      "source": {
        "from": {},
        "to": {},
        "rel": null
      }
    },
    "created_at": "2015-10-12T20:26:13Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-12T20:26:13Z",
    "type": "question",
    "subject": "test",
    "raw_subject": "test",
    "description": "test 1234",
    "priority": "normal",
    "status": "open",
    "recipient": null,
    "requester_id": 1371651941,
    "submitter_id": 1371651941,
    "assignee_id": 1371651941,
    "organization_id": 157600651,
    "group_id": 24976891,
    "collaborator_ids": [],
    "forum_topic_id": null,
    "problem_id": null,
    "has_incidents": false,
    "due_at": null,
    "tags": [
      "jpa"
    ],
    "custom_fields": [
      {
        "id": 28089621,
        "value": "jpa"
      },
      {
        "id": 28087191,
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "id": 28087201,
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "satisfaction_rating": null,
    "sharing_agreement_ids": [],
    "fields": [
      {
        "id": 28089621,
        "value": "jpa"
      },
      {
        "id": 28087191,
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "id": 28087201,
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "brand_id": 782281
  }
]
next_page:
previous_page:
count: 2
```

But now i did not know how to load the received data in Ticket Objects.

I Need something like that:

```
foreach(Ticket t in [Received Data])
{
    ... do something
}
```

to replace the "Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);" part.

These are my first steps in JSON, some how-to or first step link could be helpfull too.

(tried to get hints on http://www.newtonsoft.com/json but without sucess)

Update 1:

After the Comment from dbc (thx, for the very helpful Link) i testet a Little bit more. The variable "content":

```
var content = response.Content;
```

contains a Valid JSON string:

```
{
    "tickets": [
        {
            "url": "https://xxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json",
            "id": 2,
            "external_id": null,
            "via": {
                "channel": "web",
                "source": {
                    "from": {},
                    "to": {},
                    "rel": null
                }
            },
            "created_at": "2015-10-12T20:26:13Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-10-12T20:26:13Z",
            "type": "question",
            "subject": "test",
            "raw_subject": "test",
            "description": "test 1234",
            "priority": "normal",
            "status": "open",
            "recipient": null,
            "requester_id": 1371651941,
            "submitter_id": 1371651941,
            "assignee_id": 1371651941,
            "organization_id": 157600651,
            "group_id": 24976891,
            "collaborator_ids": [],
            "forum_topic_id": null,
            "problem_id": null,
            "has_incidents": false,
            "due_at": null,
            "tags": [
                "jpa"
            ],
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "id": 28089621,
                    "value": "jpa"
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087191,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087201,
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "satisfaction_rating": null,
            "sharing_agreement_ids": [],
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": 28089621,
                    "value": "jpa"
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087191,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087201,
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "brand_id": 782281
        },
        {
            "url": "https://xxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/3.json",
            "id": 3,
            "external_id": null,
            "via": {
                "channel": "web",
                "source": {
                    "from": {},
                    "to": {},
                    "rel": null
                }
            },
            "created_at": "2015-10-13T12:22:39Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-10-13T12:22:39Z",
            "type": null,
            "subject": "Test 2",
            "raw_subject": "Test 2",
            "description": "test content",
            "priority": null,
            "status": "open",
            "recipient": null,
            "requester_id": 1371651941,
            "submitter_id": 1371651941,
            "assignee_id": 1371651941,
            "organization_id": 157600651,
            "group_id": 24976891,
            "collaborator_ids": [],
            "forum_topic_id": null,
            "problem_id": null,
            "has_incidents": false,
            "due_at": null,
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "id": 28089621,
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087191,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087201,
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "satisfaction_rating": null,
            "sharing_agreement_ids": [],
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": 28089621,
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087191,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 28087201,
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "brand_id": 782281
        }
    ],
    "next_page": null,
    "previous_page": null,
    "count": 2
}
```

but, **only if there is NO double Quotation mark in the description** (and i think in other fields too). Seems that Zendesk API does no escaping for the Quotation Marks !?!

But anyway i have valid JSON now, how can i load the JSON string in the Ticket object?

Comment: Your JSON looks invalid:  1) It's missing outer `{}` characters  2) `"Einreichen"` is not escaped correctly.  Can you make sure it passes validation at http://jsonlint.com/, then edit and update your question?  Or is the Zendesk API returning invalid JSON?

Comment: This is the Output from the "Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);" part in the Example.

Result of jsonlint.com is:

    Parse error on line 1:
    tickets: [    {   
    ^
    Expecting '{', '['

Is there some Kind of conversion i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://92logics.zendesk.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer your_api_key"); // or your basic authentication
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string path = "api/v2/tickets.json?page=1";

ZenDeskTickets list = null;
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    long SkippedId = 1;
                    string SkippedUrl = "";
                    list = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ZenDeskTickets>();
        }
```

You need to add `namespace System.Net.Http` to access `ReadAsAsync`.
It is available as dll and also as web api package files

Here is ZenDeskTickets Calls for you.

```
public class ZenDeskTickets
{
    [JsonProperty("tickets")]
    public Ticket[] Tickets { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("next_page")]
    public object NextPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("previous_page")]
    public object PreviousPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Same way you can define Ticket Class.

Each property/column will map automatically to right location and data will be filled.